# How to put array of buttons in the left of the frame

Tags: java, arrays, button

I'm working in a project of Air-lain class 
I want to create a array of buttons to reserve seat. 
I do the array but I don't know how to put it in the left of the frame.
it is be in the whole of frame

```
int x=0;

for (int j=0 ; j<100 ;j++)
{
    a[x][j]=new JButton();
    a[x][j].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    contentPane.add(a[x][j]);
    x++;
    if(x==5)
      x=0;
}
```

also how can I put a names for the column and row out side the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a GridLayout/GridBagLayout. Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

> **GridLayout** is a very simple layout manager that can arrange components
> in a grid of rows and columns. Every cell in the grid, and thus every
> component, is resized to be the same exact size.
>
> **GridBagLayout** is much more complex, and much more flexible. It also arranges components in rows and columns, but individual components can span multiple rows or multiple columns and thus the components in the grid can vary in size.

Comment: thank you , but I know how to do the buttons , the thing is I dont know is how to order them in the right of the frame so I can put another buttons,text area .. in the left

Comment: through grid layout you can divide the screen into rows and columns. So you can put button or text where ever you want very easily. For e.g: If you need to show "Please click here --> <Button>" in your page, you need to put the textbox in row0col0 and the button in row0col1

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should illustrate your problem better. How about a simple paint image with drawing with what you want? I am sure there is insufficient information here to answer your problem.

Comment: thank you , but I don't have more than 10 reputation to post image :(

Comment: Well the the best of what I can do is to suggest you to use GridLayout, as Hirak says, in combination with BorderLayout to achieve what you want. Wish you luck.